# How on earth turn off address bar searching on edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I really couldn't find a way to turn address bar search off. I just want to go to the absolute address i typed. I know  add http:// on the front could do it. But no I just want an method only type in the domain！Like "a.service" which is a domain I created in a DNS server myself.
I know Firefox could do it by set  keyword= false on "about:config" page.
For some reason I need to use Edge.
Please HELP!!

Many answers said turn off suggestion on privacy settings, but it do not work!

Comment: Googling for a second already provided the answer here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/disable-address-bar-searching/4a513fc1-1a55-4a9d-bca9-0732e0eaf3ab Please be aware that after changing configurations you might need to restart the browser for it to work as intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such solution as setting `keyword.enabled=false` to simply turn off the "search" function of the address bar for Edge. But if you want a pure address bar for URL visiting, here's what I do:

1. Go to **Settings** --> **Privacy, search, and services** --> **Services** --> **Address bar and search** --> **Manage search engines** --> **Add**. It allows you to create a custom search engine, but we want to design it in another way.
2. In the `Add search engine` prompt, design your custom search engine. What really matters is the last box. Make sure you add `http://%s` or `https://%s`. [image]
3. Then, make sure you've made it as default search engine, so that you can simply type in URLs in the address bar.[image]

Comment: Such a brilliant idea!!

Comment: Genius! Works like a charm. <3